# Doxygen: Class diagram (grey box) without collaboration diagrams

Tags: uml, doxygen

I want to create the image for a class diagram (UML styled), without the collaboration data.

I already have Doxywizard, but don't see how to do it without the collaboration relations.
What combination of options should I use?

This is ASCII representation of what I want:

```
----------
| Foo    |
----------
| -bar1  |
| -bar2  |
----------
| +Foo() |
| +~Foo()|
----------
```

This is what I get currently:

```
----------        -----------------
| Foo    |        | OtherClass    |
----------        -----------------
| -bar1  |        | -test1        |
| -bar2  |        | -test2        | 
---------- -----> -----------------
| +Foo() |        | +OtherClass() |        
| +~Foo()|        | +~OtherClass()|
----------        -----------------
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with current doxygen release. Maybe ask this on the doxygen mailing list (as feature request) ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting COLLABORATION_GRAPH to NO?

> COLLABORATION_GRAPH If the COLLABORATION_GRAPH and HAVE_DOT tags are
>   set to YES then doxygen will generate a graph for each documented
>   class showing the direct and indirect implementation dependencies
>   (inheritance, containment, and class references variables) of the
>   class with other documented classes.